# MTOM enabled soap request from salesforce

Tags: integration

In Soap ui we have an option to make a saop request mtom enabled.  How can we do tha same when we are making a soap callout from salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

After raising a Case with Salesforce regarding this issue, I got the below reply:

Hi Montosh,

Greetings from Salesforce!

I'm Ajith from Salesforce Developer Support team and this communication is regarding the case #17454304 - How to enable Enable MTOM Feature From APEX in a SOAP request

I have taken the ownership of your Case and I am currently reviewing it. Based on the description I have understood that you have a requirement of enabling MTOM Feature From APEX SOAP request.

Kindly note that as of now we do not support MTOM and it is not included in the roadmap of future implementations. Our binary support is documented in the API guides and can be found here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm

We do support gzip compression, please find below the related article.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/SOAP_Compression

Please let me know in case of any other concerns as this particular request is out of scope for support and we have to mark it accordingly. However, for this is bring to Salesforce R&D's notice, please post an idea on Salesforce Idea Exchange.

Kindly provide us your contact details and working hours (including timezone) if you would like to discuss this in detail over a phone call. In case contact person is someone else, please share their details.

My working hours are 0800 hrs EST to 1700 hrs EST. In case you need assistance beyond my working hours, please provide the contact person details who would be available during those hours and our global support team would be available at your service.

Next follow up: 3 - 5 PM EDT, Tuesday

Regards, 
Ajith Anand 
Success Agent Senior - Tier 2 
Global Customer Success Center | Salesforce 
Working Hours: Mon-Fri | 08:00 to 17:00 EST

Answer (score 0):

I have raised an Idea for this so that it benefits someone else in the future. Please vote for the idea:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Ts4sQAC